# iOS deeplinks work wrong. Why move me to app?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I have a problem with deeplinks. I make list urls that must be defined, but when i write link in safari from outside the list, web browser move me to app. How disable moving to app from links outside the links.

```
/apple-app-site-association file:
["applinks" => [
            "apps" => [],
            "details" => [
                [
                    "appID" => "RB52FWZ72J.pl.test.Test",
                    "paths" => ["/newest", "/cams", "/cam/*", "/search/*", "/rank/*", "/online/*", "/czat", "/premium", "/messages/*", "/notification", "/viewer", "/votes/yesno", "/votes", "/friends", "/settings/*"]
                ]
            ]
        ]]
```

if i open in web browser link /forgot-password safari move me to app.

maybe add "NOT /*" in file? (on end array links ofc.)

Web browser don't move me to app when open links outside list.

Comment: Don't use the old style `paths`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks/details/components